For-Loop Not Running in an Asynchronous Function
My code ignores the for loop and just completes the function without it. I want the code to work in a parallel thread, so it can handle multiple client requests at once. I do not want to use const fs = require("fs").promises because it freezes my server for whatever reason. Any advise would be appreciated!
Here is my code:
async function MyReadFilesAsync(directoryPath, inputFileName, inputSearchTerm) {
    try
    {
        // Read the files in the directory
        //const files = await fs.readdir(directoryPath);
        await fs.readdir(directoryPath, async(err, files) => {
            if(err)
            {
                console.error(err);
            }
            
            // Filter files to include only those named "Post.data"
            const postFiles = await files.filter(filename => filename === inputFileName);

            let results = [];

            let searchTerm = inputSearchTerm.toLowerCase();
            
            if(searchTerm === "")
            {
                // Loop through filtered files
                for (let i = 0; i < postFiles.length; i++) {
                    const filename = postFiles[i];
                    const filePath = path.join(directoryPath, filename);
                    
                    // Read each file asynchronously
                    const fileContent = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8');
                    
                    // Do something with the file content here
                    //console.log(`Content of ${filename}: ${fileContent}`);
                    // Parse the JSON data
                    const sampleData = await JSON.parse(fileContent);
                    console.log("sampleData = ", sampleData);
                    

                    const result_i = {
                        fileContent: fileContent,
                    };
                    results.push(result_i);
                    if(i >= postFiles.length)
                    {
                        return results;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Loop through filtered files
                for (let i = 0; i < postFiles.length; i++) {
                    const filename = postFiles[i];
                    const filePath = path.join(directoryPath, filename);

                    // Read each file asynchronously
                    const fileContent = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8');
                    
                    // Do something with the file content here
                    //console.log(`Content of ${filename}: ${fileContent}`);
                    const sampleData = await JSON.parse(fileContent);
                    console.log("sampleData = ", sampleData);
                    
                    if(sampleData[0].title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) || sampleData[0].message.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
                    {
                        const result_i = {
                            fileContent: fileContent,
                        };
                        results.push(result_i);
                    }
                    results.push(result_i);
                    if(i >= postFiles.length)
                    {
                        return results;
                    }
                    
                }
            }

        });
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        console.error('Error reading files:', error);
    }
}

As I said, the code completes but there is no result, nor an error indicated any issues. It completes the function but the result that I get is "undefined". Thank you for your time and help.

You are confusing async/await with callbacks. They are not interchangeable. Look at Using filesystem in node.js with async / await

What you are looking for is for-await...of loop.
There are few other problems in your code:

async version of fs.readdir return files and does not accept callback.
[].filter is not  async so you don't have to await it
JSON.parse also not async
You can increase readability if you move conditional block to for-loop

here is a fixed example:
async function MyReadFilesAsync(directoryPath, inputFileName, inputSearchTerm) {
  try {
    const files = await fs.readdir(directoryPath);
    // Filter files to include only those named "Post.data"
    const postFiles = files.filter((filename) => filename === inputFileName);
    let results = [];
    let searchTerm = inputSearchTerm.toLowerCase();

    for await (const filename of postFiles) {
      const filePath = path.join(directoryPath, filename);

      const fileContent = await fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8");

      const sampleData = JSON.parse(fileContent);
      console.log("sampleData = ", sampleData);

      const result_i = {
        fileContent: fileContent,
      };
      if (searchTerm === "") {
        results.push(result_i);  
      } else {
        if (
          sampleData[0].title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
          sampleData[0].message.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
        ) {
          results.push(result_i);
        }
      }
    }
    return results;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error reading files:", error);
  }
}


I received this error:
Error reading files: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "cb" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
at line:
const files = await fs.readdir(directoryPath);
This is because I am not using promises in fs, right? When I use promises in fs, it freezes the server for whatever reason.

I've done it, thank you. For those who may be in similar position, here is what I had to change:
const fs = require("fs/promises");
const files = await fs.readdir(directoryPath, (err) => {
console.error(err)
});
Instead of const fs = require("fs").promises;

Yeah that way to import is require(“fs/promises”)
